# C# type conversion

Tags: c#

```
dr["po_amt"].ToString() = 1,936.10;
```

when i try to convert this to int32 using the below code,

```
Convert.ToInt32(dr["po_amt"].ToString());
```

it throws an error input string was not in correct format. How can i achieve this

Comment: Well, it's not an integer value, so you can't convert it to an integer. What do you want to do with the value?

Comment: What's the type of the value in dr["po_amt"]? Converting the value to string just to parse it back to its type smells badly, if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to Double and cast it to `int`

```
int i = (int)Convert.ToDouble("1203.12");
```

works :-)

Answer (score 9):

You're trying to convert "1,936.10" into an integer. That's clearly *not* an integer. You should parse it as a floating point number (e.g. with `decimal.TryParse`) and then apply whatever conversion you want to get an integer afterwards, if indeed you really *do* want an integer.

(I would *strongly* advise you to use `decimal.TryParse` over `float.TryParse` or `double.TryParse`, by the way. Obviously the string is representing a number *in decimal*, so that's the most appropriate type to use.)

When converting to `decimal`, you should specify the invariant culture (in case you're in a region which uses "." for the thousands separator and "," as the decimal separator), and it wouldn't hurt to explicitly specify the number style, allowing thousands.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert `1,936.10` to an integer, but you can convert it to a floating point and then cast it:

```
(Int32) Convert.ToDouble("1,936.10", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note the use of the `CultureInfo` to avoid problems when you run in a locale where the floating point number format is different.

Casting the floating point number will truncate the fractional part. If you need to round it you should apply the `Math.Round()` before casting it.

Comment: I think that is the best solution of this case

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing to a float then converting to Int32:

```
var d = float.Parse("1936,10");
Convert.ToInt32(d);
```